# How to get the animation paused using :active in CSS?

Tags: html, css

1. The animation 'shake' pauses when `:hover`. I am trying to get the same with `:active` but it doesn't want to pause. Why is this?
2. Second question is regarding the button: `button:active` works for three other divs but not for the first one.

I have been staring at the code for too long; how do I solve the above problems?

```css
button {
  border: none;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
button:active {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 0.1s, background-color 0.1s;
  transform: translate3d(0, -2px, 0);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: myFont;
  src: url(Demo_ConeriaScript.ttf);
}
#listmenu {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-family: myFont;
  font-size: 120%;
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s;
  transition: background-color 1s;
  animation: shake 3s cubic-bezier(.36, .07, .19, .97) both;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
#listmenu:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: black;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
#listmenu:active {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
@keyframes shake {
  0%, 95% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  96% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
    color: white;
  }
  97% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
    color: black;
  }
  98% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
    color: black;
  }
  99% {
    transform: translate3d(-2px, 0, 0);
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <button id="listmenu" onclick="openMenu()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" style="font-size: 150%; padding: 5px;"></i>
  </button>
  <button id="bplaces" onmouseover="fplaces()" onmouseout="fdefault()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" style="font-size: 150%; padding: 5px; right: 1.5px;"></i>
  </button>
  <button id="bquote" onmouseover="fquote()" onmouseout="fdefault()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book" style="font-size: 150%; padding: 5px; right: 1.5px;"></i>
  </button>
  <button id="bcontact" onmouseover="fcontact()" onmouseout="fdefault()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" style="font-size: 150%; padding: 5px; "></i>
  </button>
  <div Id="bdisplay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You simply need to remove these from your css {left: 25px; top: 25px; position: fixed;}

Comment: Looks like :hover and :active pseudo classes work as expected here in relation to animations: https://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/s4sgqzsa/

Comment: First where is the animation here? can u plz explain clearly?